# x86-64 ASM. Best way to choose register usage

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Let's suppose I have two registers (say RAX and RDX) that I can freely use without impacting sourrounding code. What is better (suppose I don't need the temporary value from 0xabcd afterwards):

```
#1
MOV RAX, [0xabcd]
MOVSX RAX, BYTE PTR [RAX]
MOV [0xbcde], RAX
```

or

```
#2
MOV RAX, [0xabcd]
MOVSX RDX, BYTE PTR [RAX]
MOV [0xbcde], RDX
```

Or is there another solution which is even better? Also would like an explanation for this in general, since I have quite a few points where I have a memory pointer at a specific address and need to dereference that pointer.

Comment: My guess is that since each instruction depends on the previous one it doesn't matter that you reuse `rax` for the value and that leaves one more slot available for register renaming in the surrounding code.

Comment: @Jester So you would say #1? Almost what I thought as well. Also is what I would prefer since it makes the program flow a bit easier to understand IMO.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  Both are fine.  In 32 bit code, the former variant has a slightly shorter encoding and may be preferred if optimising for size.  However, this is not the case with 64 bit code.